# How to resolve a System.TimeoutException during MongoDB connection?

Tags: c#, wpf, database-connection, mongodb-.net-driver, connection-timeout

I've started using the [MongoDB .Net driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/connecting/) to connect a WPF application to a MongoDB database hosted on MongoLabs.

But the following method I created to load the connection(called on the MainViewModel's constructor), threw a timeout exception on the line marked in the method below.

I tried to resolve the error further by adding an exception check of type MongoException to no avail. Also checked that the connection string is valid as per the docs and it seems so: (password starred out for security)

```
    private const string connectionString = "mongodb://<brianVarley>:<********>@ds048878.mongolab.com:48878/orders";
```

The specific error thrown is as follows:

```
An exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Complete Error Link: http://hastebin.com/funanodufa.tex

Does anyone know the reason why I'm getting the timeout on my connection method?

```
        public List<Customer> LoadCustomers()
        {
            var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            var database = client.GetDatabase("orders");
            //Get a handle on the customers collection:
            var collection = database.GetCollection<Customer>("customers");

            try
            {
                //Timeout error thrown at this line: 
                customers = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
            catch(MongoException ex)
            {
                //Log exception here:
                MessageBox.Show("A handled exception just occurred: " + ex.Message, "Connection Exception", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);          
            }

            return customers;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried connecting via mongo shell or some other method to determine if it's a server issue and not your code?

Comment: Nope, good suggestion actually, will give that a go now

Comment: I think your credentials for mongolab are invalid. I had the same issue a few weeks ago. Have you created a user for the database or are you maybe using the credentials for your mongolab account?

Comment: ok my connection string was incorrect, left these in < > . Will post an answer for anyone else with same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this error by re-editing my connection string. I had left these two symbols in my connection string in error, '<' and '>' between the user name and password credentials.

Correct format:

```
"mongodb://brianVarley:password@ds054118.mongolab.com:54118/orders";
```

Incorrect format:

```
"mongodb://<brianVarley>:<password;>@ds054118.mongolab.com:54118/orders";
```